# React-native, how to remove nextProps value from componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to know if it is possible to remove nextProps data in  componentWillReceiveProps().

In component constructor I set state 'msg' to '' to block animation run.

Next, my component receive props "msg" in function "componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp)" and later if value nextProp.msg is different than '' function set a new state 'msg' = nextProp.msg and launch animation.

When animation is finished I set state 'msg' to '' again to prevent unwanted animation run when component refresh.

Unfortunately it doesn't work because nextProp keep last passed data. So even if component is only refresh I can't block animation because 'msg' value is never empty again.

So is it possible to clear last passed data or is there any other way to block animation run if component is only refresh without passing new props.

P.S. I can't compare this.props.msg!==nextProps.msg and block animation if  are the same because sometimes I need to run 2 animation with the same value.

Thank you.
Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Animated,
    Easing,
} from 'react-native';

export default class PopUpMsg extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            msg:'',
            bottom: new Animated.Value(-50)
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp){
        if(nextProp.msg!=='' ) {
            this.setState({
                msg: nextProp.msg
            }, () => {
                this.showMsg();
            });
        }
    }

    showMsg(){
        if(this.state.msg!='') {
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(
                    this.state.bottom,
                    {
                        toValue: 0,
                        duration: 500
                    }),
                Animated.delay(1000),
                Animated.timing(this.state.bottom,
                    {
                        toValue: -50,
                        duration: 500
                    }),
            ]).start(result => {
                if (result.finished) {
                    this.setState({
                        msg:''
                    })
                  }
                });
        }
    }
    render(){

        return (
                <Animated.View style={{
                    height:50,
                    width:100+'%',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                    alignItems:'center',
                    justifyContent:'center',
                    position:'absolute',
                    bottom:this.state.bottom,
                }}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.msg}</Text>
                </Animated.View>
        )
    }

}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({

    text:{
        color:'#fff'
    }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('PopUpMsg', () => PopUpMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `nextProps` in `componentWillReceiveProps` because `nextProps` is just a static copy of the props your component is about to receive, not a reference to the actual props. What you should do in this case is either keep your message in local component state and dispatch a `setState` setting your message to `""` or, in case you're using a state container such as Redux or MobX, dispatch an action which will reset your  message.

Comment: I don't use state container. About your first part of answer, I don't really understand how should I do it. I can't setState my message to "" because nextProps change it after refresh. Or you think about something different? Regards

Comment: How about moving your logic to `componentDidUpdate` then? This way, you can get the _old_ props and compare them to the current, _and_ you can use `setState` with no issues.

Comment: It can't help me. Sometimes component can get props with the same value one after another and I can't block animation.

Comment: Then you need to change the way you're modeling this. Maybe have a second prop which indicates whether the animation should be actually ran or not. The issue here isn't really React, it's how you are modeling this that is incompatible with React's component model.